# Oracle BLOB - Undo tablespace and efficient writing to file

Tags: oracle, plsql

*Please see the pl/sql code block at the end of this post*

I am writing some pl/sql code to extract certain files from a zip.  I'm using the "as_zip" package found at http://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/as_zip7.txt to get the file names found in the zip (`AS_ZIP.GET_FILE_LIST`) and to extract certain ones into a `BLOB` (`AS_ZIP.GET_FILE`) that will then be written to a file using `UTL_FILE`.

**First question**
As far as I've seen in monitoring, the `UNDO TABLESPACE` doesn't seem to get written to during this process but I wanted to confirm with others that this is true...if I'm just extracting the contents of particular files into a `BLOB` that will then be written out to a file, would the `UNDO TABLESPACE` be impacted?  Every megabyte that the business uses on the database they're charged for so we need to always look for ways to reduce our tablespaces if at all possible...

**Second question**
In terms of writing a blob out to a file, are there more efficient ways to do it then how I've done it?  The first file (which happens to be the largest at 3.03GB) writes out to the file system nice and quick but then each subsequent file seems to write out slower and slower.  Do I need to free resources or allocate them differently or....

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
  zip_files as_zip.file_list;
  l_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  L_BUFFER RAW (32767);
  L_AMOUNT BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_pos INTEGER;
  L_BLOB BLOB;
  l_blob_len INTEGER;
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);

  ZIP_FILES  := AS_ZIP.GET_FILE_LIST( 'MY_DIR', 'MY_FILE.zip' );

  for i in zip_files.first() .. zip_files.last
  LOOP
    FOR EXT_TABLE_REC IN (SELECT LOCATION FROM USER_EXTERNAL_LOCATIONS) LOOP

      -- Check if there's a match between what's in the zip file and what the external table name is
      IF (INSTR(TRIM(LOWER(ZIP_FILES(I))),TRIM(LOWER(EXT_TABLE_REC.LOCATION || '__'))) > 0) THEN

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Match found on ' || ZIP_FILES(I) || ', ' || EXT_TABLE_REC.LOCATION || ' - processing...');  

        L_BLOB := AS_ZIP.GET_FILE('MY_DIR', 'MY_FILE.zip', zip_files(i));

        -- Open the destination file. Note the third parameter "wb"
        l_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('MY_DIR', EXT_TABLE_REC.LOCATION, 'wb');

        l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength (l_blob);

        -- Read chunks of the BLOB and write them to the file until complete.
        l_pos := 1;

        WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len
        LOOP
          DBMS_LOB.READ (l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
          UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, FALSE);
          l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
        END LOOP;

        -- Close the file.
        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (L_FILE);

      end if;

    end loop;

  end loop;

END;
/
```

In case anyone was wondering, here's what comes back for database information when I log in:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, Oracle Label Security,
OLAP, Data Mining, Oracle Database Vault and Real Application Testing options
```

**Edit 1**
I've taken out the `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS` block based on information I found on Oracle sites.  Now, the process just seems to hang, so not sure where the issue is now occurring...

Answer (score 0):

Undo for LOB segments is managed differently than normal undo for a hash table.. The undo is managed and stored as part of the lob column itself. With the pctversion paramater you can specify how much space is set aside for undo. The value is specified as percentage value.

Comment: Could you point me to the "official" documentation that this information is based off of?  I just want to read up a little more on it...thanks.

Comment: Here you go: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_tables.htm#ADLOB45279

Answer (score 0):

In the DBMS_LOB.READ call, l_amount is a IN OUT parameter and will get smaller and smaller each time threough your outer loop.  It could get as small as 1, in which case you're processing 1 byte at a time.  Right after you set l_pos := 1; also set l_amount=32767;